# Are "Publish-to-Adapter" and "Rendezvous Subscriber" compatible with each other?

Tags: tibco, tibco-rv

when i am publishing with "Publish-to-Adapter" and listening it with "Rendezvous Subscriber", an unwanted xml tag gets inserted at run-time - <__caret_1_caret_> <__caret_2_caret_>, for every repeated elements. Is there any way i can remove the tags ? because when i want any element inside the repeated elements, i cant fetch it as the above tags are not there during design time.

Comment: Why are you trying to use Publish-to-Adapter when you are publishing to an RV Subscriber?

Comment: the process containing "Publish-to-Adapter" is a simulation of external system, so we dont know exactly what is being used. "Rendezvous Subscriber" is at our end. hence we tested both the scenarios. works fine with RV Publisher- RV Subscriber, but not Publish-to-Adapter-RV Subscriber

Comment: ask the people who are creating the external system what they are using.

Answer (score 1):

they are actually not compatible, tags - <__caret_1_caret_> <__caret_2_caret_>, will always get inserted. we went ahead with RV Publisher- RV Subscriber.